# How to change the ResponseFormat from XML to JSON depending on request headers

Tags: vb.net, wcf, rest

I have a REST Service written in vb.net and be default the Response comes back as XML unless I set the `ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json`. So I was hoping that I could change the `ResponseFormat` depending on what headers the user passed in.  So I'd code my `<WebGet>` like this:

```
<WebGet(UriTemplate:="UserNames/", BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedResponse)>
Public Function UserNamesList() As List(Of UserNames)

    'check the Headers for either XML or Json and then set the ResponseFormat
    Return intUserNamesList()

End Function
```

So is there a way to set the `ResponseFormat` or equivalent outside of the `<WebGet>` declaration?

Answer (score 0):

Think I've cracked this.  I can use `WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Format = WebMessageFormat.Xml` or `WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Format = WebMessageFormat.Json` inside my function